# pip is broken and gives typeerror from_buffer() cannot return

Tags: python, pip

I was trying tto delete and reinstall pip but basically I did something bad/wrong and it doesn't work anymore. Firstly, I wanted to upgrade pip and I did `sudo python -m pip install --upgrade pip` but It didn't work, then tried `pip install -U pip` this was also not a solution and I deleted pip from usr/local/bin and .local/bin etc. (probably that was the mistake)

Then, to be sure that I completely remove it, I did `sudo apt-get --purge autoremove python-pip`. For now It was fine, at least I didn't get any error.

I install pip again by `sudo apt-get install python-pip` and when I want to do anything with pip, I get this error: [image]

I stuck at that point, I tried many different solutions from other stackoverflow suggestions but I couldn't ge further. Whatever I do, `pip -V`, `pip install <PackageName>` gives the same error. Any ideas how to get rid of it? At least I want to be sure, that I completely delete all pip-related files and reinstall pip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue by doing `sudo apt-get purge python-openssl`, then I reinstalled it.